# Загрузка готовый базы данных в приложение (SugarORM)

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

Я собираюсь заполнить базу данных с помощью  SQLiteadmin , а потом хочу подключить ее к приложению, написанный используя SugarORM. Это возможно? или sugarORM это попросту не умеет и мне нужно использовать просто sqlite.
UPD: Или любой другой способ для загрузки готовых данных в приложение.

Comment: На первое время, я решил хранить базу данных в самом приложение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно! Создайте базу как угодно и подключайте её к своему приложению, использующему sugar orm. Главное, чтобы названия полей классов (которые использует sugar) совпадали с названиями столбцов ваших таблиц (ведь вы их создадите "вручную"). Для этого вам нужно скопировать файл базы в папку assets вашего проекта. Затем, приложение при запуске будет проверять сидит ли этот файл в data/data и, если нет, скопирует его туда из assets. Это можно сделать вот так:

```
private void checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    } else {
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```