# SugarORM не использует готовую Database

Tags: java, android

Пробую использовать готовую базу данных с SugarORM, копирую DB в нужную папку `getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("data.db").getPath()`.
Заполняю все как надо в манифесте , ORM вроде видит DB но не читает содержимое, а выдает `table TABLE already exist,` таблицы созданы и именованы правильно, не пойму что дальше делать
[Руководствовался этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517370/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-sugarorm)

Копирую вот так:

```
InputStream myInput = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("data.db");
     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("data.db").getPath());
     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     int length;
     while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
         myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
     myOutput.flush();
     myOutput.close();
     myInput.close();
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="DATABASE"
        android:value="data.db" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="VERSION"
        android:value="1" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="QUERY_LOG"
        android:value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

В документации по SugarORM сказано, что версия, прописааная в манифесте не может быть меньше 2х. Вероятно в этом ваша проблема.